# Python: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ' '>

Tags: python, html, urllib

Quite new to this, so i'm unsure as to why I'm getting this error

relevant code:

```
htmlconv = open('savedlist.html','w', encoding = 'UTF-8')
filepath = 'file://'+str(path.abspath('savedlist.html'))
#prints as: file://C:\Users\....\savedlist.html

urlopen(filepath)
```

error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:''>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: @Blacksilver yes, it appears in my folder

Answer (score 0):

Try manually entering the string in the format below and see if that works.

```
filepath = 'file:///C:\\Users\\....\\savedlist.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'localhost//', it works for me.

```
filepath = 'file://localhost//' + os.path.abspath(local_file);
```